# Jmeter: Values not populated when request are generated dynamically

Tags: json, jmeter, preprocessor, dynamic-values

**Test Plan Structure**

```
TestPlan
JDBC Connection Configuration
HTTP Request Defaults
HTTP Header Manager
User Defined Values
    udvBranchCode
TestFragment
    JDBCRequest - Written query to get data from database
        JSR223 PostProcessor 
ThreadGroup - CreateTransaction
    IFController - ${__jexl3("${udvBranchCode}"== "",)} If udvBranchCode is blank then only run JDBCRequest
        ModuleController - Pointed to JDBCRequest JSR223 PostProcessor
HttpRequest
    JSR223 PreProcessor - Here checking I am checking if udvBranchCode has value; if not then value from the database will get set.
```

Below are the details
1. **JDBCRequest's JSR223 PostProcessor**

Here I am checking the resultSet size and then randomly storing the branch code as properties.

```
resultSet = vars.getObject("resultSetUserDetails")
if (resultSet.size() !=0 ) {
    Random random = new Random()
    int i = random.nextInt(vars.getObject("resultSetUserDetails").size())
    strBranchCode = vars.getObject("resultSetUserDetails").get(i).get("BranchCode")
    props.put("propsBranchCode" + ctx.getThreadNum(), strBranchCode)
}
```

2. **HttpRequest Details**  *IFController*

Here if branch code value is blank in user Defined Values then I am calling Database.

```
${__jexl3("${udvBranchCode}"== "",)}
```

3. **HttpRequest Details**

```
{
  "TR": {
     "BranchCode": "${brnCode}"  -> Here brnCode is not populating
     "CustomerType": "${udvCustomerType}"
   }
   "Individual": {
        "FirstName": "Deepak",
        "MiddleName": "Kumar",
        "LastName": "Verma",
   }
   "Company": {
        "CompanyName": "Company",
        "StartDate": "23/01/2020",
    }
}
```

4. **Above HttpRequest's JSR223 PreProcessor Details**

Here I am checking if branch code is not present in user defined values then set the code getting from the database. Also based on customer type removal of respective object/elements from the request is working fine. But for BranchCode I am getting issue, here instead of populating BranchCode values, this has been "${brnCode}" populated.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def oldRequest = new JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())

def bcode = props.get("propsBranchCode" + ctx.getThreadNum())
if (vars.get("udvBranchCode").isEmpty() == true) {
    vars.put("brnCode", bcode)
} else {
    vars.put("brnCode", vars.get("udvBranchCode"))
}

if (oldRequest.Transaction.CustomerType.equalsIgnoreCase("Individual")) {
    oldRequest.remove("Company")
}

def newRequest = new JsonOutput().toJson(oldRequest)
sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('',new JsonOutput().prettyPrint(newRequest),'')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by replacing in **HttpRequest's JSR223 PreProcessor Details**

> - vars.put("brnCode", bcode)
>       WITH
> - oldJSONRequest.TR.BranchCode = bcode

Below

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def oldRequest = new JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())

def bcode = props.get("propsBranchCode" + ctx.getThreadNum())
if (vars.get("udvBranchCode").isEmpty() == true) {
    oldJSONRequest.TR.BranchCode = bcode 
} else {
    oldJSONRequest.TR.BranchCode = vars.get("udvBranchCode")
}

if (oldRequest.Transaction.CustomerType.equalsIgnoreCase("Individual")) {
    oldRequest.remove("Company")
}

def newRequest = new JsonOutput().toJson(oldRequest)
sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('',new JsonOutput().prettyPrint(newRequest),'')
```